# Вылетает приложение при попытке обнулить пароль в Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

Пытаюсь сделать в своем приложении функцию сброса пароля, использую бд Firebase. Нашел функцию в документации: sendPasswordResetEmail. Но при  нажатии на кнопку обнулить приложение вылетает и я не понимаю почему.

MainActivity Код:

```
private void showSighInWindow() {

        String B1="Забыл пароль";
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);//отображение окна внутри формы
        dialog.setTitle("Войти");//заголовок для всплывающего окна
        dialog.setMessage("Введите данные для входа");//подпись под заголовком
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(this);//получаем нужный нам шаблон
        View sign_window=inflater.inflate(R.layout.sign_in_window,null);//помещаем шаблон в переменную
        dialog.setView(sign_window);


        final MaterialEditText email=sign_window.findViewById(R.id.emailField1);

        final MaterialEditText pass =sign_window.findViewById(R.id.passField);

        final MaterialEditText email_zap =sign_window.findViewById(R.id.emailField1);




      dialog.setNeutralButton("Забыл пароль", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                AlertDialog.Builder dialog1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                dialog1.setTitle("Войти");//заголовок для всплывающего окна
                dialog1.setMessage("Введите данные для входа");//подпись под заголовком
                LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);//получаем нужный нам шаблон
                View sign_window=inflater.inflate(R.layout.act_passs,null);//помещаем шаблон в переменную
                dialog1.setView(sign_window);

                dialog1.setNegativeButton("Отменить", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                });


                dialog1.setPositiveButton("Обнулить", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog1, int which) {


                        auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email_zap.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener((new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Успешно",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                                else {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        }));









                    }

                });
                dialog1.show();
            }

        });
```

Log:

```
 Process: com.example.telemedi, PID: 31896
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotEmpty(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.2.0:274)
            at com.example.telemedi.MainActivity$3$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:120)
            at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6617)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
    2020-02-24 14:08:23.832 31896-31896/com.example.telemedi I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 31896 SIG: 9
```

Comment: а что в логах пишет по поводу ошибки?

Comment: @Andrew прикрепил. Ругается на строку auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email_zap.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener((new OnCompleteListener<Void>()

Comment: а вы почту ввели? ошибка говорит о том что вы передаете пустую строку

Comment: @Andrew Да, когда нажимаю кнопку обновить приложение просто вылетает

Comment: мне сложно сказать точное местоположение ошибки, так как я не вижу номеров строк, но могу допустить что здесь `email_zap.getText().toString()` неправильно получаете строку с почтой, попробуйте пока закомментировать отправку данных в firebase и посмотрите через логи что именно получаете из поля для ввода.

Comment: @Andrew Проблема именно в кнопки. Я попробовал засунуть этот код в другую кнопку и он заработал. А с этой почему проблемы, я не знаю. Может ли быть проблема в том, что у меня AlertDialog открывается поверх другого AlertDialog'а?

Comment: а что находится `MainActivity.java:120` здесь?

Comment: @Andrew auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email_zap.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener((new OnCompleteListener<Void>() (я взял ее и засунул в другую кнопку и все заработало, проблема не в ней, а в кнопке)

Comment: мне кажется странным то что вы выводите один диалог поверх другого, и здесь возможна ошибка `AlertDialog.Builder dialog1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);` попробуйте указать вместо `MainActivity.this` это `dialog` но вообще это не очень правильно мне кажется

Comment: @Andrew Не, выдает ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, проблема была во view. Я сначала использовал первый View, а затем пытался использовать его повторно, к сожалению или к счастью так делать нельзя.